# Rails Capitalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For Rails `capitalization`, when I use it with a string and try to manually capitalize something else in the sentence, it won't allow me to capitalize it.

eg. `"how is New York".capitalize`

> "How is new york"

Is there anyway in Rails that allows me to ensure the first word is capitalized, but also gives flexibility that if the user capitalizes something else in the string, it will still apply?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617474/8534588

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using rails 5+ you can use `str.upcase_first`

other wise the simplest solution will be

```
str = "how is New York"
str[0] = str[0].upcase
```

Comment: Do you know how I can pull this off with an instance variable in Rails?

Comment: what you mean, you can do exactly same with instance variables also.

Comment: So if I put this in my ERB file - it just disappears completely - `<%= @portfolio.description[0].upcase! %>` - not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: that change is not in place. i updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: if not using rails 5+ you will have to use `@portfolio.description[0] = @portfolio.description[0].upcase` in your controller or a helper